# Enabling fts/n1ql on single node cluster without adding extra node

Tags: couchbase

I have single couchbase node cluster with only data service enabled.
From documentation,  we need to add one more to node to enable fts service. But i would like to enable fts on existing single node setup without deleting cluster/data/adding one more node.

Can i enable fts or any other service on existing setup. if so please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to do what you are asking for. At best you can back up your data outside the node, reconfigure the node from scratch, and reload your data. It's kind of weird that it's not possible, but when run in production, there is typically only one service per node anyway, so having to add a new server when you want a new service type is reasonable.

Comment: Thanks Johan. It was helpful. I was expecting there can be way to enable on the fly.